# Can't share internet with access point

Tags: networking, internet, lan, wireless-access-point

I connect my computer to internet with USB tethering and using my 4G internet from my mobile. I can share this internet through LAN network. But how can I use my access point to share internet that I get from USB tethering to PC?

Like this

```
                       +........+............+...........+....wifi
                       |        |            |           |
                       AP      Phone       Phone       Phone
                       |                                   
======+========+=======+====SW
      |        |       |
     PC       PC      PC
      |
  Internet
```

Comment: Like what? Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited this, please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Just bridge the two interfaces (assuming you're on windows): select both then select "share internet connection". Then connect the AP to the lan port of your PC, your mobile device will be the 'dhcp', so disable interfering ones, if present' on the lan.

But I think easyest option is to make a wirless network directly from your phone (wifi tethering), giving it same name and password as 'ap', then shutting the access point off so pc will connect to your mobile directly.[image]

[link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10) to a guide online